# 引数部分にある波括弧はどういう意味ですか？

Tags: javascript, next.js

[Layout Component - Assets, Metadata, and CSS | Learn Next.js](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/assets-metadata-css/layout-component)

に下記の記載があります。

```
export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return <div>{children}</div>
}
```

引数部の `{ children }`の意味はなんでしょうか？
JavaScriptってこんなところに`{}`は許されたでしょうか？
Next.js特有の文法なのか、babelかなにかの特殊な文法でしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[分割代入(Destructuring assignment)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) という 構文 (代入演算子)で, それを利用したものです

```js
// オブジェクトのプロパティーと同じ名前の変数で受け取る
function fn({id}) {
  console.log(id); // 123
}
fn({id: 123})

const o = {p: 42, q: true}
// オブジェクトのプロパティーとは異なる名前を持つ変数で受け取る
function fn2({p: foo, q: bar}) {
  console.log(foo); // 42
  console.log(bar); // true
}
fn2(o)
```